# IONIC APP- [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope, phonegap-plugins

I'm getting this error and have been looking for it on the google but still couldn't solve this issue.

```
 ionic.bundle.js:26799 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $cordovaCameraProvider <- $cordovaCamera <- CameraCtrl
```

app.js code given below

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ng-Cordova','starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
     .state('tab', {
      url: '/tab',
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
    })


      .state ('camera',{
       url:'/camera',
       controller:'CameraCtrl'
    })

     .state('tab.account', {
          url: '/done',
          views: {
          'tab-d': {
           templateUrl: 'templates/d.html',
           controller: 'DCtrl'
       }
    }
 });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/abc');

 });
```

Controller.js code given below

```
.controller('CameraCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaCamera) {

  document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

    var options = {
       quality: 50,
       destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
       sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
       allowEdit: true,
       encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
       targetWidth: 100,
       targetHeight: 100,
       popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
       saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
       correctOrientation:true
     };

     $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
        var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
        image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
     }, function(err) {
      // error
    });

  }, false);
})
```

on clicking this icon it should open camera to capture image

```
<a href="#/camera"><i class="icon ion-camera"></i></a>
```

Comment: I think you just need to inject ngCordova as an angular dependency into your app. Look [here](http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/#inject-as-an-angular-dependency)

Comment: Tried but then it gives this error
 Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ng-cordova due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ng-cordova' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it

Comment: If thats the case then check that you have properly done the cordova add plugin for both ngCordova and $cordovaCamera AND added the script to index.html, if you can get ngCordova to work, you'll fix this.

Comment: I have downloaded this cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera in my project and ngCordova zip file from http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/ . Added it to index.html as per instruction but couldn't get to work.

Comment: In your app.js have you inject the ngCordova and camera plugin?

Comment: angular.module('starter', ['ionic','starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'ng-cordova'])

Comment: Should be `ngCordova` not `ng-Cordova` when injecting into your app

Comment: Yes I changed that and now it shows no error. Thanks all

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this issue in below steps :

**Step 1 :** Use bower to install ngCordova

```
$ bower install ngCordova --save
```

**Step 2 :** Include ng-cordova.js or ng-cordova.min.js in your index.html file before cordova.js and after your AngularJS / Ionic file (since ngCordova depends on AngularJS).

```
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

**Step 3 :** Then, include ngCordova as a dependency in your angular module:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngCordova'])
```

**Reference :** http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/

Answer (score 1):

In **app.js** you should change this line

`angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ng-Cordova','starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])`

to this

`angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngCordova','starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])`

---

More about this in [ngCordova docs](http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/):

Inject as an Angular dependency

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngCordova'])
```